# Does wekbit have an equivalent performance API to chrome for measuring memory usage?

Tags: ios, memory, webkit, observability

Chrome has measureUserAgentSpecificMemory, which "is used to estimate the memory usage of a web application including all its iframes and workers."

Is there an equivalent for Safari?

The timelines panel in Safari's dev tools has a Memory profiler and a Javascript Allocations profiler, which display memory usage, but I'd like to poll this data via JS.